# Not Provided with Contact Info - Should I send a Thank You Note?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, united-states, consulting, email-etiquette

Context: I am currently a college student in my senior year. I have completed several internships, and am currently interviewing for full time roles.

Yesterday I completed super day (final round) interviews with two different companies (henceforth A and B). In both instances, I was provided with an interview schedule and the names of the people whom I would be speaking with. I was not provided with email addresses or contact information.

To provide a bit more context, my HR contact from company A reached out to let me know that I should expect to hear back about their decision within two weeks. Company B told me that they expect to make a decision within two business days. At this point I would strongly prefer working at company A.

Both A and B are large, well-known corporations, and in both cases I am interviewing for very competitive consulting / analyst rotation programs.

It is my understanding that it is always proper etiquette to send thank you notes to one's interviewers after an interview. My question: would it be perceived as poor etiquette if I looked up their email addresses to send thank you notes, when this information was not provided to me in the first place? Or would it be more damaging if I did not send a thank you note at all?

In both cases, my interviewers were employees who worked in roles similar to the ones that I am applying for. My HR contact/recruiter has been my point of contact for all communications regarding the application process.

I would appreciate a bit of insight concerning this matter.

Edit: The industries in question are banking and strategy consulting.

Comment: Personally, I have never sent a thank you note after an interview. I am in the US, and none of my friends or acquaintances have ever done that. Are you in the US?

Comment: If you don't have any contact information, how have you stayed in touch with your "HR contacts"?

Comment: @FerventHippo I guess he got emails of the hr people. But in an interview, some other people also take part like team lead, team members etc.. In my experience, companies normally do not share all contact data of all participants until nessessary. The contact of the interviewee is HR, not the team lead of the position itself.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica that makes sense. However, in that sense it would be good to clarify in the questions who the "interviewers" are that the asker wishes to contact.

Comment: Frame challenge: send _snail_ mail, not email. A short, handwritten note addressed to "Interviewer #1, Company A, Address at which interview took place", will show that you're rather highly interested in the position since it takes significant time, effort, energy _&_ money to buy cards, hand write them, put stamps on them and send them out. Far more effort than whipping off a quick copy/paste email. I'd image that while you'd _prefer_ Company A, you'd be inclined to accept from Company B as an about-to-be-minted college grad, as any job in your field is a good start.

Comment: I am from the US and was surprised to read @nightsurfer's comment. Every career workshop I ever attended in high school, college etc. included "send a thank-you note to the interviewers" as a standard tip. Might this be a generational and/or domain difference?

Comment: @Max my friends and I are all late 20s-early 30s. I've asked around, and quite literally, nobody has ever done this! We're also majority tech industry, which may change the context. I don't believe OP posted what industry the jobs were for.

Comment: Banking is a more conservative industry than tech so it's possible that, in general, thank you notes are still a thing with them. Sourav Ghosh's answer still applies.

Answer (score 37):

I'll make it very simple:

- If you have a communication address (email), you can send a note thanking them for the opportunity and mentioning that you're looking forward to hear from them.

  In your case, you can send the note to the HR who wrote to you. You're thanking the organisation overall for the opportunity, not the individual(s).
- If you do not have a communication address, no need to go out of the line to find out the possible address and send a note (for individual interviewer(s)). You never know how it'll be perceived, and it's not worth the risk.

Comment: Indeed, the location/culture/industry differences in expectations are interesting but a moot point here. No reasonable person is expecting to get an email from someone they never gave their email address to.

Comment: Even if you have the contact info I would still wait for the company to initiate the next contact.

Comment: @deep64blue I was suggesting to reply to the HR communication, edited to clarify.

Comment: You will likely end up just sending a note to HR but when you do so, make sure you mention something like, "Please pass on my thanks to Bob, Jim, and Susan for taking the time to consider and interview me." That way it doesn't seem like you are just thanking HR, you are expecting/asking them to pass your thanks on to the group of people that interviewed you. If you don't have or don't remember individual names, you can just make it generic like, "Please pass on my thanks to the interview panel for taking the time to consider and interview me."

Answer (score 23):

I agreed with the [Philip Kendall’s answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/187265/14273).

I am in the US, and have worked for many software companies. I have never sent a thank-you note after the interviews either. It is not necessary to do so if you are interviewed for software engineer positions.

The reason is that most interviewers are very busy. They don't have time to read those notes. They won't think that you are not polite or not interested in the jobs if you don't send them the thank-you notes. Software engineers are very practical and realistic in this aspect.

---

**Note**: However, if you work on other industries, or in different areas of the world with different cultures, then you may or may not need to send thank-you notes after the interviews. It depends.

Comment: "The reason is that most interviewers are very busy." <- I go slightly further than this: interviewing is part of my job. I'm paid to do it. There's no need for _anyone_ to go out of their way to thank me for that (possibly unless I did something exceptional).

Comment: @PhilipKendall but it can be a cultural thing also. Thanking someone may not be warranted (as they are doing their job), but sometimes it goes a long way. Obviously, that does not mean crossing the line is acceptable, but in many cases (for example: if then contact email is available), a thank you note might not harm. YMMV.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Its still out of the ordinary and not a good idea.  If you want to thank me at the end of the interview (a simple "Thanks for your time"), that's fine.  Don't bother me when I'm back doing my real work.  At best it will have no effect.  At worst it will annoy me.

Comment: As a hiring manager in the US, I've received a few thank you emails over the years. Those that were personalized and referenced specifics of the interview created a good impression; although I had already rated and recorded my thoughts about the candidates in our ATS system, the notes might have influenced subsequent consideration of their candidacy. A couple were rather generic; I don't think I held it against the candidates, but these notes conveyed neither sincere gratitude nor helped their candicacy.

Comment: While the concept of a thank you note has been all but lost, at least in the US, I think it goes above and beyond (for such a simple gesture) that shows them that you appreciate their time even if it's their job and could make you stand out a little more. Does no one thank waiters, servers, etc. at restaurants when they take your order, bring you food, etc.? That's their job but I still thank them because it's polite. If someone is offended by something as simple as a thank you note, I'd seriously question whether I would want to work with that person.

Comment: @JeffC In the context of a job interview it can create the impression that you're a suck-up. That doesn't mean the recipient is offended, but they might get a bad impression about you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think that's possible but that's more about HOW you say thank you rather than IF you say thank you. When you are in interviewing in-person, do you not say thank you when you are wrapping up? I do. This is just an extension of that.

Comment: @JeffC Waitstaff are doing their jobs, but that job is serving you; they're doing things *for you*, so it makes sense to thank them even though you know they're being paid to do it. Interviewers aren't serving you or doing anything specifically for you; they're doing things for their company, so it makes less sense to specifically thank them, but I do think it is still good to express gratitude for their time and the opportunity to interview. However, a simple thank you at the end of the interview is all that is necessary. A personal thank you note after the fact is too much.

Comment: @JeffC, Good point. However, consider this **FUN** scenario. We all thank the waiters after the meals, and interviewers at the end of interviews, which is fine. Then, next week, if we write thank-you notes to the interviewers, should we also write thank-you notes to the waiters ? **If we only write thank-you notes to the interviewers and NOT to the waiters, does it seem a little self-serving as the interviewers will decide if we get the job offers while the waiters do not decide anything?** :-) (I am criticizing your points. I am only bringing up a **FUN** scenario :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 It's never been a practice (in the US) to send thank you letters to waitstaff but it has been to send them to interviewers. I think we can both agree that finding a job is a little more significant than ordering a meal. I agree it's falling out of practice but a lot of "polite" things are these days... but that doesn't mean they aren't a good idea.

Comment: If someone sent me a thankyou note after an interview I would think that person was a little creepy to be honest, and that would be a very bad mark.

Answer (score 21):

> It is my understanding that it is always proper etiquette to send thank you notes to one's interviewers after an interview.

This is certainly not a universal truth; I have done many interviews in the UK tech industry in my time, both as an interviewee and interviewer, and never sent nor received a thank you note. And I like to think I have a pretty good record of getting job offers from those interviews - and it would make essentially zero difference to me as an interviewer if I did receive a thank you note.

Therefore my answer would be "no", but I wouldn't have sent one even if I did have their contact details. If you understand more about your location and industry and believe that it is actually beneficial to send a thank you note, you may have a different answer.

Comment: He's right. Even in the US. Don't bother with this. It's just a silly thing recruiters tell wide-eyed green-eared novices but it is rare and inconsequential when anyone actually does this.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be perceived as poor etiquette if I looked up their email
> addresses to send thank you notes, when this information was not
> provided to me in the first place?

It would be perfectly fine to do this, as long as you can determine the correct work email addresses.

As @yshavit wisely points out, send it to their work email accounts, never their personal email accounts.

Comment: Personally I would find this weird. I've conducted multiple interviews, but if I were to receive an unsolicited email from an interviewee, without giving them my work address, it would be very weird. I don't agree with this Joe, one cannot assume how this would be perceived.

Comment: While I agree with the concept of sending a thank you email, it might come across as weird if I had to look up their email somewhere outside of the email thread I was originally contacted on. I would just email back the company contacts and ask them to pass on my thanks to all who interviewed me that might not be on the email thread.

Answer (score 0):

In such case, it seems proper to me to connect with your interviewers on LinkedIn, instead of sending emails.